# DbContextScope Pattern for EF Core 3

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Some of you may be familiar with the [DbContextScope library](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope), which allows you to nest scopes within your code, and allow those scopes to share a common DbContext. The idea is that the DbContext gets managed for you by the scope library, and instead of calling SaveChanges() on the context, you call SaveChanges() on the scope. The magic happens because the scope will only save all the changes on the context at it's outer-most call of SaveChanges(), so all the nested operations performed on the DbContext get saved in a single transaction at the outer scope-level.

Now that DI is a first-class citizen in .NET Core, it appears that scopes have also become an important part of the .NET Core ecosystem, and the EF Core team, knowing this, has implemented scoping based on allowing DbContexts being injected by the DI system, and (I assume) allowing change saving to happen at scope-levels and not directly on the DbContexts in some way.

So my question are these:

- What is the appropriate way to share a DbContext via a scope, allowing the SaveChanges() be managed at the scope level and not the code-level that typically calls SaveChanges() on the DbContext?
- Are there new mechanisms in EF Core that manage this for you, just like DbContextScope did this for you as a 3rd party library?
- Save me the drama, and spare me the lectures on why you think UOW needs to be implemented in addition to EF. K thnxs bye.

UPDATE: As of 6/2020 there are several forks of DbContextScope that work with EF Core 3.

UPDATE: Forks of this project can be viewed here: https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope/network

There are several EF Core 3 versions... I haven't tried any yet, but there you go.

Comment: I think you can safely stick with DbContextScope. AmbientContext (the design pattern it follows) is a fitting solution here, just like it is for TransactionScope.

Comment: @Rafe - re: "there are several forks of DbContextScope that work with EF Core 3": Can you share links to which forks have said support? Thanks.

Comment: @DerekBromenshenkel See second update above.

Comment: @Rafe what forks you are using work with EF Core 3?

Comment: @guaike honestly, I haven't made the upgrade yet. I'm curious to know if anyone has used one of the EF Core 3 forks yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since Entity Framework 5.0.0, [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#dbcontextfactory) `IDbContextFactory<TDbContext>` that lets you control the creation *and disposal* (!!) of your DbContexts.

Instead of registering your DbContext with `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextPool`, you can now use `AddDbContextFactory` or `AddPooledDbContextFactory`, respectively.

Note that this feature takes care of *one* of the problems that `DbContextScope` solves, not all of them. As for what the other problems and solutions are, refer to Mehdi's [original post](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/). It is long but excellent.

Answer (score -2):

DbContext sharing is built-in to the Dependency Injection design for EF.

The DI container will generate a [scoped DbContext instance for each web request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#implicitly-sharing-dbcontext-instances-across-multiple-threads-via-dependency-injection).  You can share the DbContext instance from any component that has a dependency on it, and call SaveChanges(), or manage transactions in your outer controller.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is that I would have a DbContext injected into my controller and call save changes there??? That sounds like the worst place you would ever want to manage data operations. This is depressing.

Comment: You can manage the UoW wherever you want.  The DI will just handle the DbContext lifetime for you.

Comment: So there’s nothing in the scope functionality that will call save changes for you automatically?

Comment: You can create middleware which will wrap request, and call save changes at the end of the call.

Comment: The problem is that the fact _that the DbContext is available in the container_ tells you nothing about whether the current code is actually being invoked by outer code that is _aware_ of that, i.e. that will call `SaveChanges` for you. With DbContextScope, it is only ever there if the outer code has consciously created it, meaning either someone is taking responsibility for calling `SaveChanges`, or you get an exception because there is no scope. Regular scoped DI lacks this, which makes it insufficient, in my opinion.

Comment: @David Browne - The point of the DbContextScope pattern is to allow you to explicitly control the lifetime of the DbContext(s). For example, within a single web request you could have two business transactions, each of which has a separate DbContextScope. Correct me if I'm wrong, but presumably there is no way to get this level of control using .NET Core's inbuilt dependency injection framework?

Comment: Injecting a dbcontext seems like a recipe for disaster.  I'm surprised its allowed at all.  If you do anything on a different thread/task etc... your app will break.  It might work for basic web apps, but not much more.